# Laravel convert package to 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm writing a package at the moment, and im upgrading it from an old Laravel 5 package to use 5.5

I have the old service provider register method, but im unsure of how to update it for Laravel 5.5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app['package-name'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
    {
        return new PackageName;
    });
    $this->app->booting(function()
    {
        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('PackageName', 'Namespace\PackageName\Facades\PackageName');
    });
}
```

Comment: check this https://laravel-news.com/automatically-upgrade-your-laravel-app-with-shift

Comment: @DhavalChheda Shift works on upgrading complete projects, not packages doesn't it

Comment: Which Laravel version your project is on right now?

Comment: @AnshuRaj I want to build it for L5.5

Comment: What is the version of your old application?

Comment: @AnshuRaj this code comes from a L4 package

Comment: Laravel 4.0 specifically?

Comment: @AnshuRaj sorry, that was meant to be L5.0 not L4

Comment: Check the laravel upgrade guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade.
First upgrade your application from Laravel 5.0 to 5.3. L5.3 and L5.5 are similar.